# Downgrade GCC version

Tags: macos, homebrew, gcc, downgrade

How do I downgrade my GCC v5 to GCC version 4.7 ? I currently don't have Xcode installed and I am using the command line tool.

More details :

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

OS X Version : 10.11.4

Comment: That info is not for gcc it is for clang. How did you install gcc. (and why do you need the older version)

Comment: My nvcc compiler is creating problem while i'm trying to use my NVIDIA GPU. I installed gcc from home-brew. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install GCC 4.7 from Homebrew:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-versions
$ brew install gcc47
```

which will install it as `gcc-47`. If you want to install as `gcc` instead:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-47 /usr/local/bin/gcc
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can

```
  brew search gfortran
```

It will list all the versions.
Then

```
 brew install gcc@7
```

For version 7.